# Rails - change relation select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following relation:

```
class Complaint < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
  has_one :address, as: :addressable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :complaints
  has_many :personal_addresses, -> { where type: 'personal' }, as: :addressable, class_name: "Address", dependent: :destroy
end
```

When the complaint has a contact, I need to use the first personal_address from contact, and when it doesn't have, I need to use the address of complaint.

I have it already working, but now that data has starting to grow, things got slow. So I need to select all of the complaints and include the address in the same sql.

For this, I overloaded the address method in complaint with the following:

```
if self.use_contact_address && !self.contact_id.nil?
    Address.where(addressable_type: 'Contact').where(addressable_id: self.contact_id).where(type: 'personal').first
else
    read_attribute(:address)
end
```

The problem with this is that the custom select returns an array. I changed to return the first element of the array, but with this rails has made a select for each element.

Someone knows how to overload the address method to implement in a way that rails do a single select to return all of the address from the DB?

What I need: Load all the complaints from the db and do it in a way that the AR query loads the address together. But if the complaint uses contact address, I need that the AR knows that it needs to load the address using a different query.

The query I need to do is the following: Complaint.all.includes(:address)

Thanks and sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 0):

what if

```
class Contact
  def address
    personal_addresses.first.presense || complaints.first.address
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specified that I need to load all the complaints with the addresses. I improved my question with the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
@contact.complaints.all
```

This would perform one select to get all related complaints to an instance of your contact. Not sure if that would solve your issue though, as the description is a bit unclear.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I need all the complaints in the system, and not a contact complaint.

Comment: I added a section "What I need" in my question, hope it helps to describe better what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
complaints=Complaint.includes(:address, {contact: :personal_addresses}).all

complaints.first.contact.personal_adresses.first
```

it should not fire additional queries for any member of complaints when accessing to the address and contact.personal_adresses relations